# Can't login to django admin with superuser loaded via fixtures

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures

I added superuser via fixtures:

```
python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

Here my data.json:

```
    [
      {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "auth.user",
        "fields": {
            "username": "admin",
            "first_name": "admin",
            "last_name": "admin",
            "is_active": true,
            "is_superuser": true,
            "is_staff": true,
            "groups": [],
            "user_permissions": [],
            "password": "admin",
            "email": "admin@mail.com"
        }
    }
    ]
```

Then I try to login to admin but had error:

```
"Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."
```

The output

```
dumpdata auth.user --indent 4 > output.json
```

show thet

```
[
{
    "pk": 1, 
    "model": "auth.user", 
    "fields": {
        "username": "admin", 
        "first_name": "admin", 
        "last_name": "admin", 
        "is_active": true, 
        "is_superuser": true, 
        "is_staff": true, 
        "last_login": "2017-09-17T13:01:51.009Z", 
        "groups": [], 
        "user_permissions": [], 
        "password": "admin", 
        "email": "admin@mail.com", 
        "date_joined": "2017-09-17T13:01:51.009Z"
    }
}
]
```

I use django1.6 and sqlite3

What i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all well-behaved web frameworks, [Django stores passwords as hashes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords). Hashes are, by design, one-way: you cannot get a user's password from the stored hash.

I suspect that `loaddata` simply inserts data as-is into your database. The fact that `dumpdata` shows `"password": "admin"` confirms this. You won't be able to log in as a user created that way since no password will ever hash to `"admin"`.

The best solution is probably to create an `admin` user with your desired password via [`createsuperuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser), *then* use `dumpdata` to generate your fixture. `createsuperuser` will take care of hashing your password. You should see a long, random-looking string in the password field.